# Getting .part evertime i download file in using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

So i am using selenium to download a file from a website, i have issued a wait command for 35 seconds (only takes about 10 to download), in the folder where it is placed in shows everything is correct but i pass the name of the file as a parameter in my program and i always get the .part at the end, even tho the file is fully downloaded and is showing correctly on my download folder. Here is my code

```
Binary= FirefoxBinary('/home/what/Desktop/firefox/firefox-bin')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/home/jerad/Desktop/Build')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octet-
stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=Binary)
driver.get("website")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEVcrt.sp1')]").click()

working = "/home/what/Desktop/Build"
abspath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), working)
for file1 in os.listdir(abspath):
   abspath = os.path.join(working, file1)
   os.path.isfile(abspath)
time.sleep(35)
print "fnshed downloading"
return abspath
```

here is the class which is calling it (part of it)

```
j = GetUpdate()
u = jerad.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox removes the .part file and leaves the fully downloaded file in the folder at the *end* of a successful download. I think the problem with your code is that you are calling `sleep()` *after* you scan the directory for a file.

Try rearranging your code like this:

```
...

time.sleep(35)
print "fnshed downloading"
for file1 in os.listdir(abspath):
    abspath = os.path.join(working, file1)
    if os.path.isfile(abspath):
        break
return abspath
```

Alternatively, you could have Python poll the directory every second and return as soon as it finds a non-.part file:

```
...
max_polls = 35
polls = 0

while polls < max_polls:
    for file1 in os.listdir(abspath):
        if not file1.endswith('.part') and os.path.isfile(file1):
            print 'finished downloading'
            return os.path.join(working, file1)
    time.sleep(1)
    polls += 1
```

This would exit as soon as it's finished downloading, which sounds like it can only take 10 seconds.